# View/request instruction sets available on SGE host

Tags: gridengine, slurm

How can I view or request hosts that can handle a particular instruction set in SGE?

With Slurm, to view available instruction sets on each host I can use
`sinfo  --Node -o '%n %f'`,
and to submit a batch job only to, e.g., hosts with the AVX2 instruction set I can use `#SBATCH constraint=avx2`.

How can I do this in SGE?

**Edit:** So far I've come up with using `qhost | tail -n +4 | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | sort -u` to see all the available chip architectures. I can then look up which support a particular instruction set and request those architectures using `qsub ... -l arch='<...>'`, but this is a bit of a pain.